# ¿Cómo se llega del latín "gingiva" al español "encía"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, latín, cuerpo-humano

En español se denomina *gingivitis* a la inflamación de las encías. No es más que uno de esos casos en los que el término médico se basa en la palabra tal y como era en latín, aunque la palabra base haya sufrido tantos cambios. Efectivamente, si miramos en el diccionario, vemos lo siguiente:

> **[encía](https://dle.rae.es/enc%C3%ADa)**
>
> `Del lat.`*`gingīva.`*
>
> 1. f. Carne que cubre interiormente las mandíbulas y protege la dentadura.

De hecho, me llamó la atención este caso porque en portugués se dice *gengiva*, palabra que está mucho más cerca del latín original. Sin embargo, en español para llegar de *gingīva* a *encía* hacen falta muchos pasos:

- Pérdida de la *g* inicial.
- Cambio de la primera *i* en *e*.
- Cambio de la segunda *g* por *c*.
- Pérdida de la *v*.

¿Podría alguien explicar cuál fue el orden cronológico de todos estos cambios, si es posible incluyendo ejemplos de palabras que hayan sufrido cambios similares? ¿Se pueden encontrar pasos intermedios de la evolución en la literatura medieval o en diccionarios antiguos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En el paso del latín a casi todas las lenguas romances, las consonantes velares /k/ y /g/ palatalizaron frente a las vocales medias y altas. En español antiguo, particularmente, /g/ dio [ɟ] (una oclusiva palatal sonora).

En *gingīva* la primera sílaba dio eventualmente [ɟen] (la /i/ corta del latín pasó a ser laxa y luego a /e/), mientras que la segunda debe haber dado [ɟi] (la /i:/ larga permaneció como /i/). Más tarde el sonido [ɟ] inicial se perdió en español en sílaba no acentuada, donde antes se había encontrado, por ejemplo, en las palabras que descendían del latín *germanu* ("hermano") o *gelare* ("helar"). Así es como la primera sílaba de *gingīva* dio /gin/ > [ɟen] > [en].

No me consta qué ocurrió con la segunda sílaba. También aquí la /g/ palatalizó, pero en español antiguo termina apareciendo como [dzi] (tal es el sonido de la *z* de *enzia*).

Cuando las oclusivas sonoras latinas se debilitaron en fricativas entre vocales, la /d/ desapareció casi siempre, la /g/ unas cuantas y la /b/ unas pocas. A esta altura no se diferenciaba entre la [β] (fricativa bilabial sonora) descendiente de la antigua /b/, y la que descendía de la antigua /w/ latina (*v*). Y así es como se perdió la *v* en *gingiva*.

Tomado de *[Palatal Sound Change in the Romance Languages: Diachronic and Synchronic Perspectives](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=jACvDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA90&ots=Kz4cZG-Qj_&dq=gingiva%20encia&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q=gingiva%20enc%C3%ADa&f=false)* (André Zampaulo), y un poco de *From Latin to Spanish: Historical phonology and morphology of the Spanish language* (Paul M. Lloyd).

[image: p89]
[image: p90]

Answer (score 1):

Colocado secunencialmente y por el orden reconstruido de cambios:

gingīva > *gingíva > *gengiva > *ǧenǧiva > *ǧenǧía > *enzia* [end͡z̻ía] > *encía*

Los pasos (2), (3) y (4) debieron completarse hacia finales del siglo III o IV d.C, de hecho la forma /*ǧenǧiva/ puede consdiderarse el proto-romance (con excepción de Cerdeña). La forma /*ǧenǧía/ podría considerarse la forma proto-castellana, y en español medieval (s. XII) ya aparece *enzia*, que a partir del siglo XVI evoluciona a *encía*, y que luego tendrá desarrollos diferentes en la península ibércia y en América, junto con Canarias y partes de Andalucía.

Para el galaicoportugués la evolución habría sido:

(1) *ǧenǧiva > (2) *gengiva* (s. XIII) > (3) *engiva > (4) *enxiva* (s. XVI)

La forma (1) es el protorrromance, la forma (2) la forma del antiguo galaicoportugués conservada, esnecialmente, en portugués moderno, la forma (4) es la que se tiene en gallego moderno.

Para el occitanorromance se tiene:

(1) *ǧenǧiva > (2) *gengiva* > (3) *geniva* (s. XIII) > (4) *cheniva* (s. XVI)

La forma (1) sería nuevamente protorromance occidental, la forma (2) la forma proto-occitanorromance y occitano moderno, la forma (3) la simplificación del catalán, y la forma (4) la forma con ensordecimiento adicinal que encontramos en aragonés.